# Custom TypeDescriptor and AddValueChange/OnValueChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, customtypedescriptor

I’m exploring the use of custom `TypeDescriptors` to intercept when a data-bound property on a WPF control sets a CLR property. Due to reasons I need to figure out which exact control is setting a value.

If I use `INotifyPropertyChanged` I’ll get all of the different controls that subscribe to any property in my view model, not all that helpful. So I figured I’d go down the custom `TypeDescriptor` path and try the `ProperyDescriptor.AddValueChanged` and `PropertyDescriptor.OnValueChanged` way.

I can see that WPF calls `ProperyDescriptor.AddValueChanged` as expected, but my call to `ProperyDescriptor.OnValueChanged` never seems to trigger a call to `PropertyDescriptor.GetValue` and an update in the UI.

Are there some gotchas to using this stuff that I’m missing? Or are there other ways to figure out who’s subscribing to a CLR property. My alternative as I see it now would be to emit a custom proxy for the whole shebang, but I’d very much like to not have do that.

Edit: On looking at bit closer, I noticed that the delegates I get through `PropertyDescriptor.AddValueChanged` go to some internal MS helper class, so without some unreliable reflection-fu there's no way to use that to get the source control. I think I'll have to go with a custom proxy with dependency properties.

Answer (score 2):

There's an alternative that may be useful. In a binding, you can set the `NotifyOnSourceUpdated` to `True`, which will raise the control's `SourceUpdated` event when WPF updates the CLR property it's data-bound to. For example, in a `TextBox` you can write:

```
<TextBox
    Text="{Binding MyText, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}"
    SourceUpdated="TextBox_OnSourceUpdated"
    />
```

In the code-behind, you can get the exact control (the `sender`) and the name of the dependency property that updated the CLR property:

```
private void TextBox_OnSourceUpdated(object sender, DataTransferEventArgs e)
{
    var control = (TextBox)sender;
    var propertyName = e.Property.Name;
}
```

With this method, you need to know that the control was a `TextBox`, but you can probably update it to test different kinds of controls. It depends on what you need this for, really.

Comment: Thanks, that could be useful. My goal was to avoid having to do trickery in the view/viewmodel and have a base viewmodel that does it all transparently. But it would seem that might not be as easily done as I was hoping...